# format(as.Date(date), "%V") returns incorrect week number for the first day of one year

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

For the following data set `df`:

```
  date       value  year  week
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2023-01-01  69.4  2023    52
 2 2023-01-02  68.3  2023     1
 3 2023-01-03  96.2  2023     1
 4 2023-01-04  97.2  2023     1
 5 2023-01-05 100.   2023     1
 6 2023-01-06 106.   2023     1
 7 2023-01-07  78.8  2023     1
 8 2023-01-08  73.6  2023     1
 9 2023-01-09 107.   2023     2
10 2023-01-10 108.   2023     2
11 2023-01-11 108.   2023     2
12 2023-01-12 106.   2023     2
13 2023-01-13 110.   2023     2
14 2023-01-14  78.3  2023     2
15 2023-01-15  75.2  2023     2
16 2023-01-16 107.   2023     3
17 2023-01-17 104.   2023     3
18 2023-01-18  98.9  2023     3
19 2023-01-19  86.2  2023     3
20 2023-01-20  66.5  2023     3
21 2023-01-21  28.6  2023     3
22 2023-01-22  48.8  2023     3
23 2023-01-23  47.2  2023     4
24 2023-01-24  54.8  2023     4
25 2023-01-25  70.5  2023     4
26 2023-01-26  70.3  2023     4
27 2023-01-27  83.4  2023     4
28 2023-01-28 110.   2023     4
29 2023-01-29 114.   2023     4
30 2023-01-30 123.   2023     5
31 2023-01-31 127.   2023     5
32 2023-02-01 124.   2023     5
33 2023-02-02 126.   2023     5
34 2023-02-03 134.   2023     5
35 2023-02-04 103.   2023     5
36 2023-02-05  NA    2023     5
37 2023-02-06  NA    2023     6
38 2023-02-07  NA    2023     6
```

I extracted `year` and `week` in `date` through the following code, and groupby them then calculated the mean of `value` for each week, but the strange thing is that the result of the `53rd` week of 2023 appeared, while the deadline of `date` of `df` is `February 7, 2023`. Could anyone explain where this error comes from? Thanks.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date=as.Date(date)) %>% 
  mutate(across(-contains('date'), as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year(date)), 
         week = as.numeric(format(date, "%V"))
  ) %>%
  group_by(year, week) %>%  
  summarise_at(.vars = c("value"), .funs = mean)
```

Out:

```
   year  week value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2023     1  88.5
2  2023     2  98.9
3  2023     3  77.1
4  2023     4  78.6
5  2023     5  NA  
6  2023     6  NA  
7  2023    52  69.4
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19358, 19359, 19360, 19361, 
19362, 19363, 19364, 19365, 19366, 19367, 19368, 19369, 19370, 
19371, 19372, 19373, 19374, 19375, 19376, 19377, 19378, 19379, 
19380, 19381, 19382, 19383, 19384, 19385, 19386, 19387, 19388, 
19389, 19390, 19391, 19392, 19393, 19394, 19395), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(69.38, 68.29, 96.16, 97.24, 100.07, 105.6, 78.79, 
    73.6, 106.6, 107.96, 108.45, 105.56, 110.11, 78.28, 75.15, 
    106.56, 103.98, 98.91, 86.23, 66.53, 28.6, 48.81, 47.22, 
    54.84, 70.54, 70.29, 83.39, 109.73, 114.11, 122.61, 126.53, 
    123.74, 126.44, 134.4, 102.95, NA, NA, NA), year = c(2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023), week = c(52, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**NOTE:** The error reason was found, seems `format(as.Date(date), "%V")` gives an incorrect week number:

```
> format(as.Date("2023-01-01"), "%V")
[1] "52"
> week("2023-01-01")
[1] 1
```

Comment: See [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html). `%U`, `%V`, and `%W` are different standards to define weeks of the year.

Comment: Thanks, I see the explanation: Week of the year as decimal number (01–53) as defined in ISO 8601. If the week (starting on Monday) containing 1 January has four or more days in the new year, then it is considered week 1. Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year, and the next week is week 1. (Accepted but ignored on input.)

Comment: Does this mean that either `%U` or `%W` fit your expected response?

Comment: `format(as.Date("2023-01-01"), "%U")` returns `'01'`, same as `week("2023-01-01")`, fit my expected response.